# Call a function only once in UIViewController when a UIButton is clicked

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I.have been reading some questions as to how to achieve this behavior and I have seen examples of calling a function work only once by calling it inside `viewDidLoad` section, but what I am trying to do is to call a function called `savedFunc` inside a `@obj` click event the first time this UIViewController is presented because then the user will be redirected to another view that I called `SavedCanvasViewController()`

```
   @objc func returnToView(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let vsdd = SavedCanvasViewController()

        // if is the first time user is in this view call this function below
        savedFunc()
     
        vsdd.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        vsdd.modalTransitionStyle = .coverVertical
        present(vsdd, animated: true)
    }
```

Since I am going to be coming back and forward to the view controller where the `returnToView` is executed, I only want to make use of my `savedFunc` function once and ignore it whenever a user is back to this view. Is it possible to make it work like that?

Comment: Forget code for a moment and think about logic. What does `savedFunc()` do? Does it save data to a local file? If so, check for the existence of that file -- if it is there, don't show (or disable) the save button. Does it post data to a server? If so, I assume you will be retrieving that data -- and, if that succeeds, again don't show (or disable) the save button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put `returnToView` into your `viewDidLoad` it will not be executed because at the time `viewDidLoad` gets called, the view controller itself has not fully setup yet and it's not visible on the window hierarchy. So you cannot use `present`. You may think to put it in `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear`. However, it has a drawback: whenever you back from another `present` or back from `navigationController.pushViewController`, it will get called again.

So, I think this will achieve your goal. It works on a single instance of `ViewController`.

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    private var isExecuteSaveFunc = false
    
    @objc func returnToView(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let vsdd = SavedCanvasViewController()

        if !isExecuteSaveFunc {
            savedFunc()
            isExecuteSaveFunc = true
        }
     
        vsdd.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        vsdd.modalTransitionStyle = .coverVertical
        present(vsdd, animated: true)
    } 
}
```

In case you want `savedFunc` to execute once during the lifetime of the app, I think `UserDefaults` will fit.